# Display selected filters in a text box in cognos

Tags: cognos

Can someone please explain how can I display selected filters in a text box in Cognos ? I am preparing this report in cognos report studio

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: // , Did you try googling it? It's worth a google.

Answer (score 1):

// , Use the following function call:

```
ParamDisplayValue(?paramname?)
```

From the documentation:

> **ParamDisplayValue**
>   Returns a string that is the parameter display value
>   of "parameterName". This function appears in the Recruitment Report
>   sample report in the GO Data Warehouse (analysis) package.
>
> **Syntax**
>   ParamDisplayValue (’parameterName’)

Reference:

https://ots.iit.edu/sites/ots/files/elements/training-and-consulting/pdfs/Cognos%20Report%20Studio%20user%20guide.pdf

http://www.howtocognos.com/show-prompt-value-report